# Pandas set_index with Multiiindex and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am surprised by the behaviour of the `set_index` when using a `MultiIndex`.

```python
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.19.2'

In [4]: columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'a'), ('foo', 'b'), ('bar', 'c')])

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3)), columns=columns)

In [6]: df.set_index([('bar', 'c')]).columns
Out[6]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'foo'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
           labels=[[1, 1], [0, 1]])
```

Why is `('bar', 'c')` still part of the columns? It seems different from non `MultiIndex` columns since, by setting the index, it disappears from the columns.

Thanks.

Comment: It's indeed weird. Note however that `('bar', 'c')` is part of the levels, but not part of the columns: `df.set_index([('bar', 'c')]).columns.tolist()` returns `[('foo', 'a'), ('foo', 'b')]`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not notice that the levels only are unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it's weird.  It's been known for quite some time.

Here is a **[snarky]** very handy work around **[/snarky]**

change column names by mapping it onto itself...

```
df.set_index([('bar', 'c')]).rename(
    columns=df.columns.to_series().to_dict()).columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['foo'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```